# identifying and blocking suspicious attempts

Tags: concurrency, e-commerce

i am about to start work on a group-buying site. it works like this: a phone costs 100USD, but if 50 people buy it together , u get a price of 70USD.

so the website launches this offer, waits for 50 people to deposit money . once the threshold is reached, everyone is sent a coupon and that person can go and get his phone.

the problem.. there will be few offers which will be time-limited. for example, total of 100 mobile phones available only. the first 100 users can only buy it. the offer starts on 5th janissary at 11am.

now, how we can detect any suspicious attempts. like a person writing a script and buying all the 100 units.

i dont think IP based limits is a good enough criteria as REAL BUYERS may access the website using the same IP.

environment is LAMP.

Answer (score 1):

why should you care , the more you sell the more you make money :) if the transaction is made you can enforce that user can't buy with same payment method and credentials twice. And as you said user must deposit money before he can make the purchase. You can ask user credit card data before the sale is opened, that is rather good limit as scammer must use 50 different credit cards

Comment: actually the problem is like this. suppose u r selling iphone.. standard price is USD 100.. and the website offers it for USD 80. now a person can buy all (or most of them) and then re-sell it for lets say 85 USD. because of this, the merchants will run away from the website and they will find more reliable partners where the goods/items/commodities go to the real consumers rather than any other 3rd party

Comment: then ensure that each item is bought only once by checking if credit card is used for that item allready

Comment: yeah.. good suggestion but i will need to talk with the marketing guys about it :)